# Insights for proving $(x^2-1) = l(l+1)(l+2)(l+3)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, proof-writing, diophantine-equations, square-numbers

I am looking for some insights on how to prove that for every integer $l$, there exists an integer $x$ such that:

$$x^2-1 = l(l+1)(l+2)(l+3).$$

So far, what I did was:

$$x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1).$$

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$$l(l+1)(l+2)(l+3)+1=l^4+6l^3+11l^2+6l+1=(l^2+3l+1)^2$$